# How to insert data to table using json object

Tags: java, xml, json, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to add some data to a table which is in the same page. The data is taken from a from. When I submit the form it will show a different page which only contains this  ({"address":"zcxx","name":"sad"}). So I can't identify what's wrong in my application. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? this is my code. I'm using struts2 for this application

web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <display-name>Struts2 Demo App</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib  prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@taglib  prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/htme.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basic Struts 2 Application - Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome To Struts 2!</h1>


<s:form action="Viewact1">

    <s:textfield name="name" id="name" label="Your Name"/>
    <s:textfield name="address" id="address" label="Address"/>
    <s:submit label="submit" value="submit" id="submit" ></s:submit>   
</s:form>            
        <jsp:include page="/Styles.jsp" />

         <s:url var="updateuserurl" action="Viewact1"/>
        <sjg:grid
                                id="gridtable"
                                caption="Sample Table"
                                dataType="json"

                                href="%{updateuserurl}"
                                pager="true"
                                gridModel="gridModel"
                                rowList="10,15,20"
                                rowNum="10"
                                autowidth="true"
                                rownumbers="true"
                                onCompleteTopics="completetopics"
                                rowTotal="false"
                                viewrecords="true">

             <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="name"  align="center" width="30"  sortable="true"/>
             <sjg:gridColumn name="address" index="address" title="address"  align="center" width="30"  sortable="true"/>

        </sjg:grid> 

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
<package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">

    <action name="*act1" class="action.HWAction" method="View">     
        <result name="submit" type="json"></result>          
    </action>
```

Action class is HWAction.java

```
public class HWAction extends ActionSupport implements Action,ModelDriven<DataBean>{
DataBean ms = new DataBean();
InputBean msi = new InputBean();
//String result;

@Override
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("execute");
return SUCCESS;

}

@Override
public DataBean getModel() {
    System.out.println("getModel");        
    return ms;           
}

public String View(){

    System.out.println("Submit>"+msi);
    System.out.println("view");
    msi.getGridModel().add(ms);

    return "submit";
}

}
```

DataBean.java

```
public class DataBean {


private String name;
private String address;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}       
}
```

InptBean class

```
public class InputBean {

private String name;
private String address;

private List<DataBean> gridModel=new ArrayList<DataBean>();


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


public List<DataBean> getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
}

public void setGridModel(List<DataBean> gridModel) {
    this.gridModel = gridModel;
}
```

Comment: You are submitting a page to the action that returns json result, and you should do it via ajax.

Comment: Make getter and setter of gridModel on Action itself and then put the ms object there. It will work.